# VB6 read barcode while program is running in background

Tags: vb6, barcode, background-process

i have a problem to make a program that can read Barcode.
What i want to do is a program (maybe a service? i don't know) that can capture barcode from a barcode scanner while is running in background.

I have found that i can check if is plugged in a specific barcode scanner with his VID/PID, here some code:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

Dim VID As String
Dim PID As String

   'Barcode scanner
   VID = "VID_040B"
   PID = "PID_6510"
   'REV = "REV_0120"

   For Each d In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBControllerDevice")
     If InStr(d.Dependent, VID & "&" & PID) > 0 Then
       Debug.Print ("Barcode Scanner found it!")
       Debug.Print wmi.Get(d.Dependent).Description
     End If
   Next
```

How can I do that is read by my program only the input of my barcode scanner?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tell the make and model of the barcode scanner. Perhaps it has an established API. The manual will help to establish that.

Comment: The list at http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids suggests that it's a Weltrend Bar Code Reader. Is that the case? You may need the drivers that are https://ez93.com/hardware/usb/vid_040b/pid_6510/ . First stop is to find the manual.